# Which Normal Form it is?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to know the normal form of all the below schema. Here text which are in bold is primary key and text with * is foreign key. As per my understanding of normalization forms all are in 3NF.

Author (**Email**, Name, Address, Telephone1, Telephone2, Telephone3)

Publisher (**Name**, Address, URL, ABN)

WrittenBy (**Email*, ISBN***, Title*)

Book (**ISBN**, Title, Edition, Year, ListPrice, PublisherName*)

Warehouse (**Code**, Address)

StockedAt (**ISBN*, Code***, StockQty)

ShoppingCart (**CartID**, TimeStamp, ISBN, BuyPrice, Qty)

Customer (**Email**, Name, Address, CartID*)

Comment: There is far from enough for us to infer this. We don;t know the relationships between your tables The data stored. WE can't answer this. We really need DDL and DML (with your key constraints) and sample data here.

Comment: Relationship is there right? I added * for foreign Key.

Comment: So, to `Book` Has no relationships cause it has no *'s? Again, we need DDL and DML **and** Sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Written by table connecting  Author and Book

Looks like its satisfying 3NF

1NF : atomic-related data-distinct column names

2NF : 1NF + no partial dependency

3NF : 2NF + no transitive dependency